# Terraform trying to replace existing resource

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

Sorry if this is a dummy question but I'm new to terraform and I could find any documentation or anything that covers this scenario.

I have a **Resource Group = rg1**, which has a **vnet = vnet1** and a **subnet = subnet1**.

I'm trying to create a new **subnet (subnet2) in same vnet (vnet1)**, terraform is giving me the below error.

> ~ name                                           = "subnet1" ->
> "subnet2" # forces replacement
>
> Plan: 1 to add, 0 to change, 1 to destroy.

Could anyone please let me know why terraform replaces the already created subnet? Is there a possible work around?

Edit 1

Apologies for not including the code, please find the same below;

main.tf

```
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "rg" {
  name     = var.rgname
  location = var.rglocation
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "vnet" {
  name                = var.vnetname
  address_space       = [var.vnet_address_space]
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "vnet_subnets" {
  name                 = var.subnet_name
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.vnet.name
  address_prefixes     = [var.subnet_prefix]
}
```

Tfvars

```
rglocation = "westus"
rgname     = "rg1"

vnetname           = "vnet1"
vnet_address_space = "10.0.0.0/16"

subnet_name   = "subnet2"
subnet_prefix = "10.0.2.0/24"
```

Variable.tf

```
variable "rglocation" {
}
variable "rgname" {
}
variable "vnetname" {
}
variable "vnet_address_space" {
}
variable "subnet_prefix" {
}
variable "subnet_name" {
}
```

Error Message

```
Terraform will perform the following actions:

  # azurerm_subnet.vnet_subnets must be replaced
-/+ resource "azurerm_subnet" "vnet_subnets" {
      ~ address_prefix                                 = "10.0.1.0/24" -> (known after apply)
      ~ address_prefixes                               = [
          - "10.0.1.0/24",
          + "10.0.2.0/24",
        ]
      ~ id                                             = "" -> (known after apply)
      ~ name                                           = "subnet1" -> "subnet2" # forces replacement
      - service_endpoint_policy_ids                    = [] -> null
      - service_endpoints                              = [] -> null
        # (4 unchanged attributes hidden)
    }

Plan: 1 to add, 0 to change, 1 to destroy.
```

Comment: Nope, without the Terraform code nobody can say why that is happening. If you just change one value, that will happen. If you want to use one resource group and vnet to create more than one subnet, then you have to add at least one additional block of code or use `count`/`for_each`.

Comment: Please show your code with FULL error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because you are basically overwriting your TF files. So previous subnet gets destroyed for the new one. The proper way of re-using the same code for different resources is through [workspaces](https://www.terraform.io/language/state/workspaces) or by having different setups in different folders fully separated.

But it seems to me that in your case you want to add new subnet, so you will have two of them at the end. In that case, you should use [count](https://www.terraform.io/language/meta-arguments/count) or [for_each](https://www.terraform.io/language/meta-arguments/for_each). This way you will create two subnets using a loop.

For that your variables should be lists:

```
subnet_name   = ["subnet1", "subnet2"]
subnet_prefix = ["10.0.1.0/24","10.0.2.0/24"]
```

then

```
resource "azurerm_subnet" "vnet_subnets" {
  count                = length(var.subnet_name)
  name                 = var.subnet_name[count.index]
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.vnet.name
  address_prefixes     = [var.subnet_prefix[count.index]]
}
```

Comment: My intension was to create a the subnet2 at a later stage. I tried with a different workspace and that work. Thanks Marcin